# Prove that $\sqrt{1+x} < 1+\frac{1}{2}x$ if $x>0$ using MVT

Tags: calculus, inequality, solution-verification, mean-value-theorem

Prove that $$\sqrt{1+x} < 1+\frac{1}{2}x \enspace $$ for $x > 0$ by  using the mean value theorem:

we have that if the function is continuous at some point the secant line is parallel to the tangent line
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Lets take $f(x) =\sqrt{1+x} $
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}$$
now $g(x) = 1+ \frac{1}{2}x $
$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{2}$$

How can I continue this proof?

Comment: Any hints?.....

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3433037/42969

Comment: @MartinR I  would like to see a more detailed explained answer than that one

Comment: The answer of @trancelocation is quite clear, assuming $0<p<1$. And in your problem ($p=\frac12$) it is the case.

Comment: @user there is a better way to solve the problem

Comment: If you're familiar with strictly concave functions and the inequality $f(x) < f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)$, then the proof is obvious for $y=0$.